# npm run build returns Module not found: Error: Can't resolve in my docker container in my NuxtJS app

Tags: node.js, docker, nuxt.js

I've been on this issue for hours now. I kept receiving the error below when I run `npm run build`

```
ERROR in ./store/chatroom.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/services/ChatRoomService.js' in '/usr/src/app/store'
 @ ./store/chatroom.js 1:0-60 9:11-26
 @ ./.nuxt/store.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./.nuxt/client.js
```

What's weird is, it is working perfectly on my local alone. The error aboves occur in my `docker build` and when I run my container with my codebase in it.. However, it is that weirder when I run my container with bind mount on my local and try `npm run build` it is working properly..

At first I thought that maybe some files from my local are missing but I tried copying every file in my local to my container via `docker cp .` but it still does not work..

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:8.12.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3000

COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install

# To include everything
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**chatroom.js**

```
import ChatRoomService from "@/services/ChatRoomService.js";
export const state = () => ({});
export const mutations = {};
export const actions = {
  getText({ commit }, data) {
    return ChatRoomService.queryText(data).then(response => {
      if (response.code === 1) {
        commit("bbs/SET_TOP_ARR", JSON.parse(response.data.content), {
          root: true
        });
      }
    });
  }
};
```

**chatRoomService.js**

```
import { mainApiClient, requestSetup } from "@/assets/js/axios.js";

const apiModule = "chatroom";

const resources = {
  chatroomGetChatRoomText: "text/queryText"
};

export default {
  queryText(body) {
    const resource = resources.chatroomGetChatRoomText;
    const [api, req] = requestSetup(resource, body, apiModule);
    return mainApiClient.post(api, req);
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you show a snippet of your 1) Dockerfile: how you copy your local codebase in? 2) docker-compose.yaml or docker command where you bind mount on your local and it works properly?

Comment: I did some edits. Kindly check

Comment: The command “docker cp” seems to cause some confusion here. Can you create a new container and mount your codebase using the flag “-v” instead. Basically, I am trying to create a new container that follow the Dockerfile here!

Comment: I already solved it.. It was how I imported. I imported `chatRoomService.js` where it should have been `ChatRoomService.js`

Comment: Cool, glad that you have it working now!

Comment: You did the same thing here. Do not put answers within the question.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

I have solved it. It was how I imported. I imported `chatRoomService.js`where it should have been `ChatRoomService.js`. It works just fine in my local because it is Mac but when I put it in a node linux server inside container it is more sensitive